# Help with applying thales theorem

Tags: geometry

Given: $MN||AB$ And $MO:AO = 3 : 5$ Find $CN:NA$ Here is drawing:
[image]

I'm sure I have to apply the basic proportional theorem, however I don't see how. The answer is $3:2$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using that $\triangle{NOM}$ and $\triangle{BOA}$ are similar and that $\triangle{CNM}$ and $\triangle{CAB}$ are similar, we have
$$CN : CA=NM : AB=MO : AO=3 : 5$$
The result follows from this.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\frac{CN}{NA} = \frac{CM}{MB} = \frac ab$. Then we have: $\frac{CB}{MB} = \frac{a+b}{b}$. Now using Menelaus Theorem on $\triangle MAC$ and line $N-O-B$ we obtain:

$$\frac{AN}{CN} \times \frac{CB}{MB} \times \frac{MO}{AO} = 1$$

Substituting the given values we get that $\frac ab = \frac 32$